# How calculate sum of positive values in each variable of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have dataframe with any number of numeric variables

```
d <- data.frame(X1 = c(-1, -2, 0), X2 = c(10, 4, NA), X3 = c(-4, NA, NA))
```

How I may calculate the sum of positive values for each variable to keep them in the list, and if the variable has no positive values or all the values NA, return to this variable is 0.

Comment: What specific result would be correct for this example?

Comment: One way often proposed by akrun: `colSums( (d*(d>0))^!is.na(d) )` which will give zero if all are NA or negative.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `apply` and `ifelse` functions to iterate through each column and replace `NA` or negative values with `0`

```
apply(d, 2, function(x) sum(ifelse(is.na(x) | x < 0, 0, x)))
```

#### Edit - concision

As @joel.wilson pointed out, there is a more concise way of coding the logic:

```
apply(d, 2, function(x) sum(x[x > 0], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: sum(x[x>0], na.rm=T) should be enough I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
library(expss)
d <- data.frame(X1 = c(-1, -2, 0), X2 = c(10, 4, NA), X3 = c(-4, NA, NA))
sum_col_if(gt(0), d)
# X1 X2 X3 
# 0 14  0
```